# SQL GROUP BY VS individually selecting data

Tags: sql

I have a sports database with table of players and then table of goals and penalties. Each goal has a scorer (player_id), time_scored, period, match, etc. The same goes for penalties (and other stats).

Now I want to show my data in datagrid. It is a table of players which could be filtered and sorted. There will be players listed with theirs stats (goals count, penalty minutes summed, etc.).

I am currently doing it like this, I select all the players from
database, then in C# I iterate over them and for each I run queries to count theirs goals (COUNT goals WHERE player_id = p.id), penalties, etc.

I wonder, will the GROUP BY statement be faster? How is it implemented? So I will group players and for each select goals count and so on. Or is there even a better way?

Comment: Can you please provide supporting data/examples?

Comment: So if you have 100 players, you're going to burden the database with, what 5-600 queries? To get data you can get with a single query?

Comment: So how should I do it? Join all the tables? Won't it be too much rows then? If I will have like 10 000 players and 1 000 000 stats?

Comment: Why would it be too many rows? If you have 10 000 players you'll have to think about how you present the data, regardless of how you get the data from the db

Comment: I think I will do COUNT* GROUP BY player_id on every stat and these tables join to the player table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that metrics are counted wrong, best is to join to sub-queries that each aggregate a different table.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  player.id as "PlayerId" 
, player.name AS "Player"
, COALESCE(goal.period, penalty.period) AS "Period" 
, goal.TimeScored
, penalty.PenaltyMinutes
FROM 
(
  SELECT player_id, period
  , SUM(time_scored) AS TimeScored
  FROM goals
  GROUP BY player_id, period
) goal
FULL JOIN 
(
  SELECT player_id, period
  , SUM(penalty_minutes) AS PenaltyMinutes
  FROM penalties
  GROUP BY player_id, period
) penalty 
  ON penalty.player_id = goal.player_id
 AND penalty.period = goal.period
LEFT JOIN players AS player
  ON player.id IN (goal.player_id, penalty.player_id)
```